# Magento layout basics

Tags: magento

Im going through a version of No-frills Magento Layout (perhaps 4-5 months old) and am basically stuck right in the beginning.

In Indexcontroller, in the index action, I create a new block object.

```
public function indexAction()
{
    //$this->loadLayout();
    $block = new Mage_Core_Block_Template();
    $block->setTemplate('helloworld.phtml');
    //print_r($block->getTemplateFile());
    echo $block->toHtml();
    //$this->renderLayout();
```

I should then create a template file, namely helloworld.phtml and place it in the appropriate directory. I'm used to using a layout file to do this, but I am going through the book and am simply not able to render the file.

I have placed the phtml file in the following locations :

```
.../app/design/frontend/default/default/template
.../app/design/frontend/base/default/template
```

which is also the output of

```
print_r($block->getTemplateFile());
```

Im obviously missing something here. any chance someone can point it out?

cheers

Comment: The first thing I'd check is if you're getting to your controller action without an error.  Try adding some var_dump(\_\_METHOD\_\_); calls at the start and end of your method to make sure the controller action is being called.

Comment: Also, and this is No Frills specific, some people have reported problems copying and pasting code directly from the PDF file.  Specifically, there's a hard to perceive space that gets inserted between the second quote of any template paramater.  It sounds silly, but try retyping the 'helloworld.phtml' paramater in your text editor.

Comment: Shouldnt the block be created through a layout object?

Comment: @vague The first four chapters of No Frills Magento Layout walk you through how the underlying PHP Block and Layout objects work, and use those examples to explain the how and why of the Layout XML system.

Comment: Hi Alan, thanks for the prompt response. yes this is No-frills specific. Really enjoying the approach to it all. im not a magento noobie but i admit that ideas get crossed when learning something in a haphazourd fashion. I am sure the controller action is being called. in fact when i print_r($block->getTemplateFile());
it tells me the path is set as : /app/design/frontend/base/default/template which is where i have placed hello world. yes, you should not copy paste as the quotation marks in the pdf will not work. im going to continue trying. i know it should work!

Comment: @activeDev I'd jump directly to to PHP file for the Mage_Core_Block_Template class (app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php).  Look for the "include" line and add some debugging that var_dump's whatever file Magento is trying to include OR add some debugging around the conditionals to determine why this isn't getting called.

Comment: Perhaps check the template file has read permissions for the web user. Also turn on logging and watch for errors. When developing I like to be extra strict and put the lines `php_flag display_errors on` and `SetEnv MAGE_IS_DEVELOPER_MODE true` in the .htaccess file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the comments above,  I'd jump directly to to PHP file for the `Mage_Core_Block_Template` class

```
app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php
```

Look for the `include` line and add some debugging that `var_dump`s whatever file Magento is trying to include OR add some debugging around the conditionals to determine why this isn't getting called.

Comment: Hi Alan. im not really sure what to do now, seeing that I have restarted the entire example and its all working now. I can only imagine i made a mistake somewhere which i have managed not to do the second time around. what would be the correct thing to in terms of this question? No Frills is great thanks very much!

Comment: I can make one point in terms using your No Frills book, is the following. Do not be lazy like me. Copy pasting code out of a PDF is a silly idea. rewrite the code yourself. this was my main issue. the answer is usually the simplest :) should i close the quesion?